# Issues getting flow to send the correct json in body when using powerautomate's http request

Tags: power-automate, smartsheet-api

I'm using a PowerAutomate Flow to call a native SmartSheet API that does a POST.  The POST IS working but my MULTI_PICKLIST type field is not being populated correctly in SmartSheet due to the double quotes.

The API is: concat('https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/', variables('vSheetID'), '/rows')

In the Body section of the http rest API I form my JSON and the section of interest looks like this:

```
{
    "columnId": 6945615984781188,
    "objectValue": {
      "objectType": "MULTI_PICKLIST",
      "values": [
        @{variables('vServices')}
      ]
    }
  }
```

My variable vServices raw output looks like:

```
{
    "body": 
    {
        "name": "vServices",
        "value": "Test1, Test2"
    }
}
```

The format needs to be like this (it works using PostMan).

```
{
    "columnId": 6945615984781188,
    "objectValue": {
      "objectType": "MULTI_PICKLIST",
      "values": [
        "Test1","Test2"
      ]
    }
}
```

As a step in formatting my vServices variable I tried to do a replace function to replace the ',' with a '","' but this ultimately ends up as a \",\"

Any suggestion on how to get around this? Again, ultimately I need the desired JSON Body to read but haven't been able to achieve this in the Body section:

```
{
    "columnId": 6945615984781188,
    "objectValue": {
      "objectType": "MULTI_PICKLIST",
      "values": [
        "Test1","Test2"
      ]
    }
}
```

vs this (when using replace function).

```
{
    "columnId": 6945615984781188,
    "objectValue": {
      "objectType": "MULTI_PICKLIST",
      "values": [
        "Test1\",\"Test2"
      ]
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Is the answer described in this other SO post any help? >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57431335/how-to-escape-quotes-in-json-within-microsoft-flow

Comment: Another potential helpful (non-SO) post >> https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Escaped-double-quotes-and-Parse-JSON/td-p/938273

Comment: And another >> https://www.encodian.com/blog/escape-double-quotes-in-json-using-power-automate/

Comment: The main issue is that I do not want the \ character in my JSON Body.  If it is there then when the POST happens it actually causes the the values array to be an array of 1 instead of 2 values.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue by taking the original variable, sending it to a compose step that did a split on the separator of a comma.  I then added a step to set a new variable to the output of the compose step.  This left me with a perfectly setup array in the exact format I needed!  This seemed to resolve any of the issues I was having with double quotes and escape sequences.